# JS Create array of objects containing random unique numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, unique

In javascript I want to create an array of 20 objects containing 2 random numbers between 1 and 250. All numbers in the array I want to be unique from each other. Basically like this:

```js
const matches = [
    { player1: 1, player2: 2 },
    { player1: 3, player2: 4 },
    { player1: 5, player2: 6 },
    { player1: 7, player2: 8 },
    ...
]
// all unique numbers
```

I have found this other method

```js
const indexes = [];
while (indexes.length <= 8) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 249) + 1;
    if (indexes.indexOf(index) === -1) indexes.push(index);
}
```

But this only returns an array of numbers:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...]
```

Comment: Hi dubs_tep, if an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.from` method to create an array of objects and then also create custom function that will use `while` loop and `Set` to generate random numbers.

```js
const set = new Set()

function getRandom() {
  let result = null;

  while (!result) {
    let n = parseInt(Math.random() * 250)
    if (set.has(n)) continue
    else set.add(result = n)
  }

  return result
}

const result = Array.from(Array(20), () => ({
  player1: getRandom(),
  player2: getRandom()
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of 251 elements (0-250) and preset all values to 0 to keep track of the generated elements. Once a value is generated, you mark that value in the array as 1.

Check below:

```js
// create an array of 251 elements (0-250) and set the values to 0
let array = Array.from({ length: 251 }, () => 0);

let matches = [];

function getRandomUniqueInt() {
  // generate untill we find a value which hasn't already been generated
  do {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 249) + 1;
  } while(array[num] !== 0);
  
  // mark the value as generated
  array[num] = 1;
  
  return num;
}

while (matches.length <= 4) {
  let obj = { "player1" : getRandomUniqueInt(), "player2" : getRandomUniqueInt() };
  matches.push(obj);
}
          
console.log(matches);
```